# Why keep 'previous' while deleting duplicates in linked list?

Tags: list, linked-list, duplicates, hashtable

i was wondering if anyone could explain what is the purpose of using the 'LinkedListNode previous' variable. i understand the general idea of trying to remove the duplicate. you look through the linked list, and if a value is not in the hashtable, insert it. but if it is, what is it doing? im not really sure.

thanks a bunch for helping! i would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain it in a clear and easy to understand way. thanks!

```
public static void deleteDups(LinkedListNode n) {
    Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
    LinkedListNode previous = null;
    while (n != null) {
        if (table.containsKey(n.data)) previous.next = n.next;
        else {
            table.put(n.data, true);
            previous = n;
        }
        n = n.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without the "previous", how would the linked-list cons chain remain connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the "previous", how would the linked-list cons chain remain connected?

Imagine: `Prev->Current->Next` which needs to be turned into `Prev->Next` if the `Current` item is to be removed from the list. If `Prev` wasn't saved temporarily then it couldn't be mutated to update the linking. (If the list was a doubly-linked list then `Prev` wouldn't be needed because it could be restored from `Current->previous`).

Happy coding.

---

In response to question in comment:

If nothing is done then the duplicate item is not disconnect from the list. `n = n.next` changes the value of `n` (but does not change the data of the element/node stored in `n` or elsewhere so `Prev.next` is never changed from `Current`).

What *needs* to be done is the the *`next` of `Prev`, the element/node* before the deleted element, must be updated to refer to the element (`Next`) after the deleted element.

```
previous.next = n.next; // and this does it
```

(This could also be written in a functional non-mutative style where the original list is not modified and a new list is built -- in that case there would be no need for `Prev`).

Comment: Isn't the deleting just skipping over the duplicate element? If so, then inside the 'if' statement, couldn't you just do...nothing? And then at the end of the while loop, it will increment n with n = n.next so then it now look at the next element?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void deleteDup( LinkedList* h){

    if( !h || !h->next )
        return;
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    LinkedListNode* previous = h;
    LinkedListNode* curr = h->next;
    while( curr ){
        if( ht.containsKey() ){
            previous->next = curr->next;
            free(curr);
            curr = previous->next;

        }
        else{
            ht.put(curr->data, true );
             previous = curr;
             curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}
```